CanvasKit's MakePicture method returning null
I am reading a .skp file in javascript as ArrayBuffer. Then trying to convert it into picture by using CanvasKit's [MakePictue] method.
But picture is null.
I have verified in https://skia.org/docs/dev/tools/debugger/ that the .skp is not corrupt. Also similar code works fine in C++ .
I first tried rendering .skp file through C++ like so and it worked fine.
const char* skpFilePath2 = <path>;
  SkFILEStream stream2(skpFilePath2);
  sk_sp<SkPicture> skPicture2 = SkPicture::MakeFromStream(&stream2);
  canvas->drawPicture(skPicture2.get());

Then I tried to do the same in javascript using CanvasKit's MakePicture method . like so.
document.getElementById('skp-file').addEventListener('change',function (e) {
    console.log('File Received');
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        console.log('File is not null');
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            const buffer = e.target.result;
            CanvasKitInit({
                locateFile: (file) => `https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.39.1/bin/${file}`
            }).then((CanvasKit) => {
                console.log('buffer:',buffer);
                const picture = CanvasKit.MakePicture(buffer);
                console.log('Picture:',picture);
                const surface = CanvasKit.MakeCanvasSurface(canvas);
                if(surface) {
                    console.log("Surface is created");
                    const canvasKitCanvas = surface.getCanvas();
                    const paint = new CanvasKit.Paint();
                    canvasKitCanvas.clear(CanvasKit.WHITE);
                    canvasKitCanvas.drawPicture(picture);
                    surface.flush();
                }else {
                    console.error('Failed to create CanvasSurface');
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});

But the result of MakePicture method is null even though the buffer is not null.
Seems like I am not reading it properly vis javascript.  Need some help here
